# Sorting two non-sequential arrays to one array ascending

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, nonsequential

I was trying to sort two arrays with non sequential numbers into one array after I did with sequential numbers. Do I need to order the arrays separately or is there a more effective way?

If I run the code below my output will be 4,16,2,11,19.. and it should be 0,1,2,3,4..

```
    int myFirstArray [] = { 16, 2, 11, 34, 77, 1, 0, 10, 3 };
    int mySecondArray [] = { 4, 19, 6, 32, 8, 10, 66 };
    int firstPos = 0, secondPos = 0;

    int myThirdArray [] = new int[myFirstArray.length + mySecondArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < myThirdArray.length; i++) {
        if (firstPos < myFirstArray.length && secondPos < mySecondArray.length) {
            if (mySecondArray[secondPos] < myFirstArray[firstPos]) {
                myThirdArray[i] = mySecondArray[secondPos];
                secondPos++;
            }
            else {
                myThirdArray[i] = myFirstArray[firstPos];
                firstPos++;
            }       
        }
        else if (secondPos < mySecondArray.length) {
            myThirdArray[i] = mySecondArray[secondPos];
            secondPos++;
        }
        else {
            myThirdArray[i] = myFirstArray[firstPos];
            firstPos++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < myThirdArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(myThirdArray[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use standard API for sorting or is this homework?

Comment: No, it's not. Just a logic thing. I know you could use API stuff but I would try it without using existing methods (like Array.sort()).

Comment: without sorting using any APIs, I would think, then, that you would have to compare each element from array 2 to array 1 to find the lowest number.

Comment: Somehow you need to know you are "currently holding" a reference to the smallest unvisited value "remaining" in each of the first two arrays.  You can achieve that by either sorting both source arrays and looping through them as above, or by finding the smallest unvisited value in either source array every time you add a value to the destination array.

Comment: As both arrays are unsorted, the most efficient way will be to use existing sort algorithms, like merge sort. However, if one of the arrays was already sorted, it might be possible to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Why not combine the two unsorted arrays into a third unsorted array and then use your favorite sort on the third array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had 2 sorted arrays and want to combine them into one sorted array then your code would be correct. But you are comparing the first 2 elements of your unsorted arrays and create a topically sorted array, meaning some elements of the array are sorted compared to others ie `4 < 16`, `2 < 11 < 19`.

Your logic is not far away from [Mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). You split your array into halves and split them again and merges the 2 halves. You end up merging arrays of size 1, then merging arrays of size 2 and so on and so on. Your merging code is correct. You can see more details  [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/).

```
// Merges two subarrays of arr[].
// First subarray is arr[l..m]
// Second subarray is arr[m+1..r]
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    // Find sizes of two subarrays to be merged
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;

    /* Create temp arrays */
    int L[] = new int [n1];
    int R[] = new int [n2];

    /*Copy data to temp arrays*/
    for (int i=0; i<n1; ++i)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (int j=0; j<n2; ++j)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];


    /* Merge the temp arrays */

    // Initial indexes of first and second subarrays
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    // Initial index of merged subarry array
    int k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy remaining elements of L[] if any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy remaining elements of R[] if any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

// Main function that sorts arr[l..r] using
// merge()
void sort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        // Find the middle point
        int m = (l+r)/2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        sort(arr, l, m);
        sort(arr , m+1, r);

        // Merge the sorted halves
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to sort your both arrays first and then merge both the array in single array.

```
// Function to merge array in sorted order
// a[] will be the first unsorted array.
// b[] will be the second unsorted array.
public static int[] sortedMerge(int a[], int b[]){

    int n = a.length;
    int m = b.length;
    int totalSize=n+m;

    //result array
    int[] res =new int[totalSize];

    // Sorting a[] and b[]
    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);

    // Merge two sorted arrays into res[]
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < n && j < m) {
        if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
            res[k] = a[i];
            i += 1;
            k += 1;
        } else {
            res[k] = b[j];
            j += 1;
            k += 1;
        }
    }    

    while (i < n) {  // Merging remaining
                     // elements of a[] (if any)
        res[k] = a[i];
        i += 1;
        k += 1;
    }    
    while (j < m) {   // Merging remaining
                     // elements of b[] (if any)
        res[k] = b[j];
        j += 1;
        k += 1;
    }
 return res;
}
```

This way the Time Complexity will be O(nlogn + mlogm + (n + m)) and 
Space Complexity will be O ( (n + m) ). If you think to merge the array first and then sort the merged array then the space complexity will be the same but time complexity will change to O((n + m)(log(n + m))), which will be definitely higher than first one .

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new `array3` with size sum of `array1.length` and `array2.length`
2. use `System.arrayCopy()` to copy `array1` to `array3` starting at index `0`
3. use `System.arrayCopy()` to copy `array2` to `array3` starting at index `array1.length`
4. sort `array3` in the way you prefer e.g. `Arrays.sort()` or any `other algorithm`